# Mix Swift and ObjC from a Development Pod Framework

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods

For a software project consisting of multiple private git modules and some locally defined Podspecs I'm trying to introduce Swift as a programming language. Unfortunately I seem to be running into some problems getting ObjC/Swift code mixing to work when importing said submodules as a framework. I already reduced my problem to the bare minimum code to rule out any weird dependency issues so this is what it looks like right now.

Basically I have the following workspace:

```
SomeProject.xcworkspace
-> SomeProject.xcproject
--> SomeProject/
---> <Some App Code>
-> SomeFramework/
--> SomeFramework.xcproject
--> SomeFramework/
---> ObjC.h
---> ObjC.m
---> Swift.swift
```

This project is managed by the following Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, "8.0"

workspace 'SomeProject.xcworkspace'

project 'SomeProject.xcodeproj'
project 'SomeFramework/SomeFramework.xcodeproj'

target "SomeProject" do

    project 'SomeProject'

    pod 'SomeFramework', source = { :path => './SomeFramework' }
end

target :SomeFramework do 
    project 'SomeFramework/SomeFramework.xcodeproj'

end
```

The podspec for the Framework looks as follows:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name         = 'SomeFramework'
    s.version      = '1.0.0'
    s.summary      = 'Some Framework.'
    s.author       = { 'Author' => 'author@me.com' }
    s.source       = { :path => '.' }
    s.homepage = "<url>"
    s.license = "MIT"
    s.platform     = :ios
    s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'

    s.source_files = 'SomeFramework/*'

    s.resource  = "SomeFramework.podspec"

    s.ios.frameworks   = 'Foundation'
end
```

Essentially, in the framework both the Swift and ObjC class have a method that prints something. In my SomeProject, I am able to reach both functions just fine.

The problem arises when I try to mix the two classes from within the Framework though.

If I try to use the Swift class from the ObjC class and import it as

```
#import "SomeFramework-Swift.h"
```

the Framework compiles just fine, but the Project itself cannot find the import statement of the generated Dependency Pod (after a new pod install ofcourse). If I try to import it as

```
#import <SomeFramework/SomeFramework-Swift.h>
```

the Framework itself is unable to compile.

Im kind of at a loss at what I am missing here by now. I made the framework a dynamic library, Ive enabled Defines Module and Ive cleaned Derived Data multiple times. If it even possible to mix and match ObjC/Swift from a framework (Swift documentation suggests it is). Anyone see what I could be missing?

Comment: So you can't include the swift header in the umbrella file, it's automatically included via modules. This only becomes an issue if you try to use that pod from a file without modules enabled. That said... I wouldn't mix swift and Objective-C in the same framework yet. Stick to Objective-C and use the nullability and other swift support annotations.

Comment: It **is** possible; the ReactiveCocoa project publishes a CocoaPod which, for their later releases, is a combined Swift/Objective-C framework.  You might check that out as a reference for how they set things up, especially in the project file, to see if there's any clues to what you might be missing:  https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa.  That said, I'm pretty sure they've set up the dependencies as one-way:  Swift (newer) classes import/use the (older) Objective-C classes, but not the other way around.